# Finding regex patterns regardless of spaces

Tags: python, regex, pandas

There are strings (which are rows of a `pandas` data frame):

`2.5807003.49 9/2020 24,54 4.7103181.69 9 /2020 172,05 4.7197189.46 09/2020 172,0 5 4.7861901.25 9/2020 8 9,16`
`2.5807003.49 10/2020 35,65 4.7103181.69 10/2020 185,50 4.7197189.46 1 0/2020 185,5 0 4.7861901.25 10/2020 94 ,32`

What I need is to extract the following information from these lines (comma is decimal separator here):

`order_id    date    sum`
`2.5807003.49 09/2020  24,54`
`4.7103181.69 09/2020 172,05`
`4.7197189.46 09/2020 172,05`
`4.7861901.25 09/2020  89,16`
`2.5807003.49 10/2020  35,65`
`4.7103181.69 10/2020 185,50`
`4.7197189.46 10/2020 185,50`
`4.7861901.25 10/2020  94,32`

- There are only 4 distinct `order_id` and they always have the same structure;
- month in `date` can have one or two digits;
- date itself may (or may not) contain spaces! E.g. `9 /2020` or `9/2020`, `10/2020` or `1 0/2020`;
- `sum` always has two digits after `,` but, unfortunately, may (or not) also contain spaces: `24,54`, `172,0 5`, `185,5 0`, `94 ,32`.

This is how I thought about it:
First step would be to split orders.
Obviously, the information related to a given `order_id` is anchored by `,` -- there are 4 orders and 4 commas in each line.
So, find comma, then go forward two digits (regardless of spaces) after it, and finally look back till the beginning of line or the end of previous order.
But even here I'm stuck since I don't understand how to catch two digits after comma regardless of spaces (if any).

Comment: Use ``` for code formatting \`\`\`code\`\`\`

Comment: can we have spaces in the year `2020` as well, for example `2 020`, `2 0 2 0`, `202 0`, `20 20`?

Comment: It can only be one space in the whole `date` or `sum`. I.e. `9 /2020` or `9/2 020` is possible, but `0 9 / 2 0 2 0` - not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input df

```
    vals
0   2.5807003.49 9/2020 24,54 4.7103181.69 9 /2020 172,0 5 4.7197189.46 09/2020 172,0 5
1   4.7861901.25 9/2020 8 9,16
2   2.5807003.49 10/2020 35,65 4.7103181.69 10/2020 185,50 4.7197189.46 1 0/2020 185,5 0
3   4.7861901.25 10/2020 94 ,32
```

Now, as multiple rows in the expected df is combined in a single row in original df, it is better to first convert the whole `vals` column to a single string

```
str1 = "\n".join(df['vals'].values)
str1

2.5807003.49 9/2020 24,54 4.7103181.69 9 /2020 172,0 5 4.7197189.46 09/2020 172,0 5
4.7861901.25 9/2020 8 9,16
2.5807003.49 10/2020 35,65 4.7103181.69 10/2020 185,50 4.7197189.46 1 0/2020 185,5 0
4.7861901.25 10/2020 94 ,32
```

Now using `findall` get all the final records. All the three required columns are in separate capture groups. `order_id` is `([\d\.]+)`. As it has no space, it is straight forward. `date` is `(\d\s?\d?\s?\/\s?(?:\d\s?){3}\d)` where space can be anywhere in the date. `sum` is `[\d\s]+,\s?\d\s?\d)` which has two digits after the comma.

```
req_vals = re.findall(r'([\d\.]+)\s*(\d\s?\d?\s?\/\s?(?:\d\s?){3}\d)\s*([\d\s]+,\s?\d\s?\d)',str1)
req_vals
[('2.5807003.49', '9/2020', '24,54'),
 ('4.7103181.69', '9 /2020', '172,0 5'),
 ('4.7197189.46', '09/2020', '172,0 5'),
 ('4.7861901.25', '9/2020', '8 9,16'),
 ('2.5807003.49', '10/2020', '35,65'),
 ('4.7103181.69', '10/2020', '185,50'),
 ('4.7197189.46', '1 0/2020', '185,5 0'),
 ('4.7861901.25', '10/2020', '94 ,32')]
```

Lastly, In Output dataframe, space can be removed.

```
final_df = (pd.DataFrame(req_vals, columns=['order_id', 'date', 'sum'])
            .replace(r'\s', '', regex=True))
final_df

      order_id      date    sum
0   2.5807003.49    9/2020  24,54
1   4.7103181.69    9/2020  172,05
2   4.7197189.46    09/2020 172,05
3   4.7861901.25    9/2020  89,16
4   2.5807003.49    10/2020 35,65
5   4.7103181.69    10/2020 185,50
6   4.7197189.46    10/2020 185,50
7   4.7861901.25    10/2020 94,32
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex that could work for the provided example:

```
(2\.5807003\.49|4\.7103181\.69|4\.7197189\.46|4\.7861901\.25)\s+([\d\s]+\/\d{4})\s+([\d\s]+,[\d\s]+)(?:\s|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VLc53D/1/

Or if there can be a space in the year:

```
(2\.5807003\.49|4\.7103181\.69|4\.7197189\.46|4\.7861901\.25)\s+([\d\s]+\/[\d\s]+)\s+([\d\s]+,[\d\s]+)(?:\s|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/LjcF3Q/1/

Comment: You should (re)read the question. What about 1 space inside date?